Microphone is not worked when app in background and screen is locked (only after i call setActive())
I have a voip app where i use the telecom API powered by android to receive calls , when i answer the call i do the following
@Override
  public void onAnswer() {
  super.onAnswer();
  startForeground(SERVICE_TYPE_MICROPHONE,notification,ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MICROPHONE);
  startForeground(200, notification, ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_PHONE_CALL);
  setActive();  // the problematic function 
// the rest of logic to answer the call

  } 

To summarize , i use class that extend ConnectionService and use onAnswer inside the connection.
My problem is that when i receive a call where app in background and screen is locked while setActive() is being called , the mic is not accessible or working , but if i comment out setActive() , the mic is working perfectly but then the logic of answer the call from telecom api break and get me in an infinite loop where i need to answer multiple time

Android 9 and above have introduced restrictions on apps running in the background, which includes limiting access to the microphone. Apps running in the background cannot access the microphone unless they are running a foreground service or have the RECORD_AUDIO permission.

hey @BobSmith thanks for your reply , but i already run it as a foreground service you can check my code above , or do you mean i should run the whole connection service as a foreground service ?

Check this link for implementation https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/foreground-service-in-android/
